# Draw random numbers from restricted Pareto distribution

Tags: r, random

Am a newcomer to R and need advice on how to draw random numbers from a limited area of a Pareto Distribution with parameters s & beta. (System: Windows 7, R 2.15.2.)

(1) I have data in a vector data$t; each single data point I'll call data&tx

For these data the parameters s & beta of a Pareto distribution are estimated following https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27426/how-do-i-fit-a-set-of-data-to-a-pareto-distribution-in-r

```
pareto.MLE <- function(X)
{
n <- length(X)
m <- min(X)
a <- n/sum(log(X)-log(m))
return( c(m,a) ) 
}
```

(2) Now I need to draw as many random numbers (RndNew) von this Pareto distribution (s, beta, see (1)) as there are observations (= data points: data$tx) . For the draw the area from which random numbers are drawn must be limited to the area where RndNewx >= data$tx; in other words: RndNewx must never be smaller than the corresponding data$tx.

Question: how to tell R to restrict the area of a Pareto distribution from which to draw a random number to be RndNewx >= data$tx?

Thanks a million for any help!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The standard approach to sampling from a truncated distribution has three steps.  Here's an example with the normal distribution so you can get the idea.

```
n <- 1000
lower_bound <- -1
upper_bound <- 1
```

Apply the CDF to your lower and upper bounds to find the quantiles of the edges of your distribution.

```
(quantiles <- pnorm(c(lower_bound, upper_bound)))
# [1] 0.1586553 0.8413447
```

Sample from a uniform distribution between those quantiles.

```
uniform_random_numbers <- runif(n, quantiles[1], quantiles[2])
```

Apply the inverse CDF.

```
truncated_normal_random_numbers <- qnorm(uniform_random_numbers)
```

[image: truncated normal random numbers]

---

The CDF for the pareto distribution is

```
ppareto <- function(x, scale, shape)
{
  ifelse(x > scale, 1 - (scale / x) ^ shape, 0)
}
```

And the inverse is

```
qpareto <- function(y, scale, shape)
{
  ifelse(
    y >= 0 & y <= 1,
    scale * ((1 - y) ^ (-1 / shape)),
    NaN
  )
}
```

We can rework the above example to use these Pareto functions.

```
n <- 1000
scale <- 1
shape <- 1
lower_bound <- 2
upper_bound <- 10

(quantiles <- ppareto(c(lower_bound, upper_bound), scale, shape))
uniform_random_numbers <- runif(n, quantiles[1], quantiles[2])    
truncated_pareto_random_numbers <- qpareto(uniform_random_numbers, scale, shape)
```

[image: truncated Pareto distrbution]

---

To make it easier to reuse this code, we can wrap it into a function.  The lower and upper bounds have default values that match the range of the distribution, so if you don't pass values in, then you'll get a non-truncated Pareto distribution.

```
rpareto <- function(n, scale, shape, lower_bound = scale, upper_bound = Inf)
{
  quantiles <- ppareto(c(lower_bound, upper_bound), scale, shape)
  uniform_random_numbers <- runif(n, quantiles[1], quantiles[2])    
  qpareto(uniform_random_numbers, scale, shape)
}
```

Comment: That's exellent. Thanks a million!

Comment: Impressively well written.  Could you please get a job writing User Manuals for Microsoft?  :-)

Comment: Glad you liked it.  Might have to pass on the user manual writing, but I have got a book on R in the works.

Comment: Sorry, two more question: if 'm' and 'a' have been calculated as outlined in pareto.MLE <- function(X) (see question), how can one find the lower_bound and upper_bound which you defined as 2 and 10 respectively? Secondly:why do you use NaN in the formula for the inverse (you had not done so in your first answer)? Thanks

Comment: You stated the lower limit in the question : `data$tx`, and if there isn't an upper limit, use `Inf`.  The inverse CDF only makes mathematical sense for inputs between 0 and 1.  (The input refers to the position in the distribution.)  I got `qpareto` to return `NaN` for dodgy inputs to make it consistent with the functions in base R.  Try `qnorm(1.5)`.

Comment: Don't understand. let's use a brief example: let say data$tx is the vector (989,1066,0,504,637,1055,0,408,135,0,1014,1038,0,0,841,85,0,1096,925,0,1040,0,0,0,0,0). my (from historic data) calculated Pareto distribution parameters are  structure(c(78.286960572671, 1073), .Names = c("s", "beta")). What are the variates to be used - in your terminology - for m,a,upper_bound, lower_bound?  Am very sorry, i learned i should have provided numeric examples from the beginning. thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I've renamed `m` to `scale` and `a` to `shape`.  These are the usual Pareto distribution parameters.  If `data$tx` is a vector rather than a scalar, then I don't think your question quite makes sense.  Have a think about what you mean when you say you want to create random numbers greater than `data$tx`.

Comment: Thanks for renaming!!!! The draw of the random numbers (RndNew) von this Pareto distribution (s, beta) needs to be drawn such that the new RndNewx are equal or bigger than data$tx. following your explanation this means to determine the cdf for each variate (e.g. cdf of 989, cdf of 1066 etc) in the vector I provided, then do a uniform random draw between cdf and 1 (your second line), and then inverse the cdf using the above pareto parameter again (e.g. inverse cdf of 989, inverse cdf of 1083, etc). What is the your lower_/upper_bound in my example e.g. for calculation the cdf of 989, 1066 etc?

Comment: Do you possibly mean by upper_bound simply max(data$tx) i.e. the largest possible variate, and lower_bound the min(data$tx) i.e. the smallest possible variate in ???

Comment: Phew! If you're happy with the answer, click the tick next to my answer to mark it as solved.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant. Thank you, Richie :)

Comment: For the PDF we can use something like this:
dpareto <- function(x, shape=1, scale=1) shape * scale^shape / x^(shape + 1)

Comment: Is there a way to get integer random values from this function directly? One could of course use something like `round(rpareto(n = 100, scale= 1, shape = 1 ,lower_bound = 1, upper_bound = 50)*10,0)`, but I am not sure if this introduces some kind of bias.

Comment: @hannes101 The Pareto distribution is a continuous distribution, so by default it will return `numeric` values rather than `integer`s. Are you sure that you aren't getting mixed up with the Poisson distribution?

Comment: @RichieCotton, I know, that for these cases a discrete probability distribution would be better, but the distribution I am looking for should be Pareto and I just would like to make sure that the integers created in this manner still follow the Pareto distribution and I think that's the case, at least when I was looking at the empirical distribution function of the resulting random numbers.